# C# Rpg Random Enemy Assignment

Tags: c#

I am trying to assigned a Enemy enemy class instance to a random newenemy instance. 
For example:

```
public Enemy GetEnemy()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Enemy newenemy = new Enemy(string.Empty, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (Main.level == 1)
        {
            int z = rand.Next(0, 2);

            if (z == 0)
            {
                newenemy = new Enemy("Chicken", 50, 0, 4, 11, 32); 
            }

            else if (z == 1)
            {
                newenemy = new Enemy("Common Goblin", 67, 0, 8, 14, 36); 
            }

            else if (z == 2)
            {
                newenemy = new Enemy("Rabbit", 50, 0, 15, 25, 9); 
            }
        }

        return newenemy;
    }
```

Which is then used in my Battle function: (I'll post some cause it is somewhat long)

```
if (whathappen == 2 || whathappen == 4 || whathappen == 6 || whathappen == 8 || whathappen == 10) //battle code
        {

            Console.Write("You were engaged by the enemy!  \nYou are fighting an enemy {0}\n", GetEnemy().name);

            while (Main.health > 0 || GetEnemy().health > 0)
            {
                Console.Write("1) Attack With Weapon ");
                int choose;
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choose); 

                if (choose == 1)
                {
                    int miss = r.Next(0, 6);

                    if (miss < 6)
                    {
                        int totaldamage = (r.Next(0, Main.RHand.damage) + r.Next(0, Main.LHand.damage)) - GetEnemy().armor;
                        GetEnemy().health -= totaldamage;
                        Console.WriteLine("You attack the {0} with a {1} and deal {2} damage!", GetEnemy().name, Main.RHand.name, totaldamage);
                        Console.WriteLine("The {0} has {1} health remaning!", GetEnemy().name, GetEnemy().health);
```

However, when I am testing my game, no enemy is assigned during the battle and I don't understand why.  This is the output:

You were engaged by the enemy!
You are fighting an enemy! (The enemy name should come after enemy)

You attack the (name should be here again) with a Bronze Dagger and deal 15 damage!

Can anyone explain why this is happeneing?

Comment: Are you sure `Main.level` is set to `1`? Run it through the debugger and validate the values are what you expect them to be. See where the logical flow deviates from what you intended and why.

Comment: I would put a breakpoint inside the GetEnemy function. It seems to not assign a name if Main.Level isn't set

Answer (score 3):

There's a few problems with your code:

- Based on your description of your problem, my guess is that `Main.level` is not equal to 1
- You're not quite using `Random.Next` correctly: `Random.Next(0, 2)` will never equal 2

But even after you fix those problems, you have a bigger issue that you're creating way too many instances of your `Enemy` and you aren't saving them anywhere.

Every time you call your `GetEnemy()` method you're making a *brand new instance* of your class, accessing one property on it, then it's getting discarded. You are attempting to maintain the state of your enemy, you will need to save the instance you create and reuse it, e.g.:

```
Enemy enemy = GetEnemy();
while (Main.health > 0 || enemy.health > 0)
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```